# Why "_links" returned for Single resource and "links" returned for retrieving collection via REST call

Tags: spring, rest, spring-hateoas

I have developed a REST API which can return a collection of Object or a Single Resource as per the Request. I have also added "self" link on each object Programmatically (Spring Hateos).

```
Link self = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(TenantController.class).slash(tenant.getTenantId()).withSelfRel();
tenantResource.add(self);
```

When the response body is returned I am getting "_links" on single resource GET where as "links" on getting the collection. why is this difference ?

```
URL (GET) - http://localhost:8080/tenants

Response (it has "links")
========================
[
  {
    "tenantId": "56c98ebb42d34bd98763f61a",
    "name": "ONGC India",
    "abbreviation": "ONGC",
    "description": "ONGC India is a Indian Organization",
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/tenants/56c98ebb42d34bd98763f61a"
      }
    ]
  }
]

==========================================================================  
URL (GET) - http://localhost:8080/tenants/56c98ebb42d34bd98763f61a

Response (it has "_links")
==========================
{
  "tenantId" : "56c98ebb42d34bd98763f61a",
  "name" : "ONGC India",
  "abbreviation" : "ONGC",
  "description" : "ONGC India is a Indian Organization",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/tenants/56c98ebb42d34bd98763f61a"
    }
  }
}
```